# Reading and writing object array list to text file

Tags: java, serialization

```
 public void readList () {
        try {
            FileOutputStream writeData = new FileOutputStream("Accounts.txt");
            ObjectOutputStream writeStream = new ObjectOutputStream(writeData);
            writeStream.writeObject(AccountCredentials);
            writeStream.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void writeList() {
        try {
            FileInputStream readData = new FileInputStream("Accounts.txt");
            ObjectInputStream readStream = new ObjectInputStream(readData);
            AccountCredentials = (ArrayList <Accounts>) readStream.readObject();
            readStream.close();
            System.out.println(AccountCredentials.size());
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

My readList method works fine right, I have `¬í sr java.util.ArrayListxÒ™Ça I sizexp    w`    
in the file. My writeList does not. I have a School folder inside the Netbeans folder, and in the main directory is Accounts.txt. Do I need to specify that? My Java file is in Schools/src. It always says my list size is 0

Comment: `readList` uses a `FileOutputStream` and `writeList` uses a `FileInputStream`. Is that intended?

Comment: Yes, one is to ready my list and output it as a text file, other is write to a list through the text file

Comment: Can you provide an initialization part of your code where you create and fill the 'AccountCredentials' variable? I've run your code locally and everything works fine.

Comment: https://onecompiler.com/java/3wzu7rat8

Answer (score -1):

Can you please share the exception or stack trace you are getting and paste it here ? , Also I would highly recommend not to use a flat file for storing the account credentials, rather use any of the identity management solution and db driven account management. Did you also try to debug the following line  "ObjectInputStream readStream = new ObjectInputStream(readData);"

Comment: All I get is run:
0
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: Listening on javadebug
User program running
User program finished

Comment: Can you please debug the 2nd line in the writeList method and check ?

Comment: How exactly do I do that on Netbeans

Comment: The first step is to set a breakpoint close to wherever you want to start stepping. Then you just step. At the top of the IDE, in debugging mode, there are buttons for debugging and when it stops at your breakpoint you'll be able to use Step In or Step Over as well as Continue. Step In can actually take you inside the line depending on what that line does, so you're looking for Step Over. Please do read the below documentation for more info  [link] https://netbeans.apache.org/kb/docs/java/debug-visual.html